# How can I rate the predictive power of a function through a heatmap?

Tags: ranking, rating, heatmap

**Context**: I use a certain function that is supposed to estimate the possibility of an event "B" to occur in a given area, following the occurence of event "A". The input is a map of the area, and the location at which event "A" occurred. The output is a heatmap encoding the confidence for event "B" to occur across all locations (pixels).

E.g., below are two heatmaps produced by the function. A star marks the *true* location at which "B" occurred.

[image]

**The problem:**
I wish to rate the predictive capability of the function, using the true location at which event "B" occurred. Ideally, the map would have a global maximum at the true location of "B". The worst heatmap would show high confidence anywhere but the true location of "B". The question is how to rate any heatmap in between.

**What I have so far:**
Of course, it is not enough to have high confidence value where "B" occured for a heatmap to be ranked high: As the left heatmap shows, multiple locations may share the same high confidence value. In such case, the high confidence at the location of "B" becomes less significant and the predictive power of the heatmap is low.

I would say in order to be ranked high, the heatmap is required to show high confidence mainly at the location of “b”, and less in other locations. I try to express this mathematically as follows:

`Pb * (1-c/N)`

Where *p* is the percentile of the confidence value at the true location of “B”, *c* is the cumulative sum of locations with confidence values of equal or higher percentiles, and N is the total number of locations.

To demonstrate, I applied this formula to some confidence distribution using Excel: the higher is the percentile of the confidence value at the location of "B", the higher is the rank. However, if many locations share confidence values of the same percentile, the rate for that percentile decreases.

E.g., if 150 (instead of 15) locations shared confidence values at the 90-th percentile, the for that percentile would be 54.5. This would also make the rate of the 100-th percentile increase because the relative number of locations with that percentile becomes smaller.

[image]

**My question**: Frankly, I rather apply a commonly used formula than to use my own. If you know of a known way to express the requirement described above, I would be glad to know. Otherwise, I would appreciate your opinion on my approach to rate the predictive power of the function I described.

Comment: I think this can be solved by using a predictive probability distribution. The overall probability mass is limited, thus when you predict one spot as very likely it follows that the others are not as likely. This is a bit like trying to predict which horse will win a race. If you are very sure that one horse wins you are very sure that the others will not. You can calculate the average (log) probability of the true data to measure the quality of your model.